# Raspberry Pi Heats up Rapidly

Tags: pi-1

For weeks, I have used my Pi (1 model B) and it worked perfectly fine. Suddenly, when I used it, it shut down and stopped working. When I tried to reconnect the power, the power button very faintly lit up red and the ACT button was not on. The Pi heats up, then the power button switches off. 
Is it completely fried, or can I save it somehow?

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: As Scotty would say to Kirk "He's dead Jim." https://tenor.com/view/star-trek-hes-dead-jim-gif-11747425

Comment: When this happened to me the guilty party was a faulty OS, that did not regulate power consumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the SDCard out, connect the power and see if either of the big chips get hot.

If any part of your Raspberry Pi gets too hot to touch within seconds of you powering up the device then it's fried. The only way to fix it costs between $5 and $35 depending which model you buy to replace the corpse.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of ways that this could happen. firstly your pi is probably overheating, you should use a heat sink or a fan to cool it down. The red light will be on always if your power supply is working, so you might want to check your power supply to make sure it is working correctly and not giving too much or too little power. And if you have been using your pi for a very long time it could have just stopped workind.

Comment: A Pi getting hot very fast after boot is a symptom of a dead Pi.  A Pi does not require a heat sink or fan for any normal usage.