# Rpi does not boot but the processor heats up very fast

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

A few secs ago my rpi workes fine and then, while i writing a file, it stopped working and after reconnect the power cable the green light stay dark and just the processor heats up. (raspberry pi zero w)

Comment: Sounds like your Pi is dead. What else was connected? What psu?

Comment: standar usb charging adapter

Comment: If your using a charger I suggest you can an actual power supply https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi Heats up Rapidly](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91274/raspberry-pi-heats-up-rapidly)